# How can I debug a 32-bits WCF service on a 64-bits machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf

I have a WCF service that depends on 32-bit DLLs, and as such it needs to run in 32-bits mode. However, on a 64-bits Windows 7 machine, Visual Studio 2010 starts WcfServiceHost.exe in 64-bits, and when it tries to load my service, it throws a `BadImageFormatException`.

How can I debug a 32-bits WCF service on a 64-bits machine?

Comment: Seems duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727313/badimageformatexception-encountered-with-wcfsvchost-and-iis-wcf-host

Comment: @CraigA, it has no satisfying answers for the Visual Studio case and mostly focuses on IIS hosting the service. But yeah, it's the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `WcfServiceHost.exe` will always run 64bit on a 64bit system.  You can [explicitly modify it to run in 32bit](http://controlflow.info/?p=9), but this is a fairly harsh workaround.

I typically will write my own hosting application, and use it to debug the service directly instead of using `WcfServiceHost` if you need to control the runtime mode.