# Wcf service host use 64bit tools while application is targeted on x86 platform

Tags: visual-studio, wcf

On VS 2017, When i debug a x86 wcf service host application. I get a BadImageFormat Exception.
I think VS2017 use 64bits tools to execute WCF Service Host.
How i can force VS2017 to use x86 version of WCF Service tools?

See the joined picture
[image]

Comment: see; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872172/how-can-i-debug-a-32-bits-wcf-service-on-a-64-bits-machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here: http://celeron533.blogspot.fr/2013/02/debug-x86-wcf-service-on-x64-platform.html

1. Open Visual Studio Command prompt as administrator
2. Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE
3. copy WcfSvcHost.exe => WcfSvcHost.old.exe
4. corflags /32BIT+ /FORCE WcfSvcHost.exe